# How to use mongodb ref foreign keys? Mongoose & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, foreign-keys

I'm a little new mongodb but currently learning the JAMStack. I come from a python/sql background.

So for a little fun project to learn these new languages, I'm building a book database kinda thing.

As of current, I have 3 collections.
First is users - contains objID, username & hashed pw.
Second collection is bookstore, which contains books added to the database. 
Third collection is called userBooks/library, which is basically the collection of books the user has, eg

```
const userBooks = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    bookid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book'},
});
```

This worked 100% fine. I could add books logged into my user account, however the problem came when I made a new user account, and wanted to add a book that already exists in userBooks.

This is the error:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: bookstore.libraries index:
>   bookid_1 dup key.

It's acting like it's got a unique: 'true' constraint, but I'm honestly not sure.

Any ideas?

Are my approach and Schema with MongoDB just completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, `libraries` in `bookstore` is marked unique. Your trying to insert same value   again on libraries

Answer (score 0):

Mate of mine helped me fix it over at https://t.me/MongodbHelp

It appears the indexes was messed up.
I ran this in the collections:

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
db.collection.dropIndexes()
```

and it fixed the errors.

Thanks!